# Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! - Error while trying to configure Spring Batch in JHipster Web Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, jhipster

I am trying to create a Spring Batch configuration to perform a batch task in my web app. I am using JHipster generator to create the rest of the app. I have finished the batch configuration, but when I try to start the application I get the following error.

```
Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether JPA or JDBC access.
```

JHipster by uses HibernateTransactionManager but the error says that it is using JpaTransactionManager. I have tried creating a duplicate transaction manager using the @Primary and @Qualifier but still no luck.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
    [ERROR] org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - JobRepository failure forcing rollback
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether JPA or JDBC access.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:449) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) [spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:210) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:227) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:121) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:115) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1809) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
[ERROR] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step sendEmailNotificationsStep in job sendEmailNotificationsJob
org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException: JobRepository failure forcing rollback
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:459) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:210) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:227) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:121) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:115) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1809) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether JPA or JDBC access.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:449) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: did u solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, you have to prevent spring from creating a JPATransactionManager. 
so I solve the problem simply by creating a Bean with the same name as BasicBatchConfigurer.

```
@Component
@Primary
public class BasicBatchConfigurer implements BatchConfigurer {

    @Inject
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @Inject
    private BatchProperties properties;
    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    public BasicBatchConfigurer() {
    }

    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    public BatchProperties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        return jobRepository;
    }

    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        return jobExplorer;
    }

    protected JobExplorer createJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        String tablePrefix = this.properties.getTablePrefix();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(tablePrefix)) {
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
        }
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    protected JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        if (this.entityManagerFactory != null) {
            factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
        }
        String tablePrefix = this.properties.getTablePrefix();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(tablePrefix)) {
            factory.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
        }
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            this.jobRepository = createJobRepository();
            this.jobLauncher = createJobLauncher();
            this.jobExplorer = createJobExplorer();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize Spring Batch", ex);
        }
    }

}
```